# Get an ID value held within a tag, but varies in each of the same class tag, using BeautifulSoup

Tags: navigation, beautifulsoup, tags, urllib

I am scraping a website where the data I am after is held within a div class:

```
<div class="cat 108070288">
```

I can extract these as containers using

```
containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : re.compile("cat.*")})
```

This gives me all of the containers I need.

What I am after is the "cat number". So I do this:

```
for container in containers:
    print container.get("class")
```

This produces a list like this:

```
[u'cat', u'119482588']
[u'cat', u'119317618']
[u'cat', u'109582818']
[u'cat', u'119089813']
[u'cat', u'118819718']
[u'cat', u'118728418']
[u'cat', u'106407623']
```

How do I get only the ID? I.e,

```
119482588
119317618
109582818
119089813
118819718
118728418
106407623
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out:

```
container.get("class")[1]
```

gives me

```
u'106407623'
```

which is what I was after